# What is the correct present indicative of *svellere*?

Tags: verbs

Treccani (https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/svellere/) and DOP (http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=18486&r=28474) agree that *svellere* can be conjugated regularly in the present indicative, but they disagree on what the irregular conjugation is: Treccano says *svelgo*, *svelli*, while DOP says *svelgo*, *svelgi*.

Can anybody offer any insight? What do other sources say?

Comment: Welcome to ItalianSE!

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Treccani only gives *svelgo* as an alternative form for just the 1st person.

DOP, as you say, gives as basic conjugation the one with *svello* (implying *svelli*, *svelle* etc.) while *svelgo*, *svelgi* is denoted “meno com.” (= “less usual”). So, both Treccani and DOP agree on *svello*, *svelli* as the main conjugation.

Zingarelli too gives this as the main form, while giving, for the 1st singular and 3rd plural persons, also alternative forms *svelgo* and *svelgono* as “disusato” (= “no more in use”). The Grande Dizionario della Lingua Italiana [refers](http://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol/20?seq=610) to *divellere* for the conjugation, and for the [latter verb](http://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol/4?seq=862) simply gives both *divello* and *divelgo*.

All in all, the normal conjugation is *svello*, *svelli*, *svelle* etc., while some forms of the conjugation with “g” have appeared somewhere, sometime, but are less usual.